# Busca ignorando acentuação na AWS CloudSearch

Tags: query, algoritmo-de-busca, amazon-aws

Estou utilizando o AWS Cloudsearch, e minha dúvida é sobre como eu efetuar uma busca simples, como "bone", e ele retornar os registros que contenham "boné", ou "tenis" e retornar os registros com "tênis".

Li na documentação da Amazon que ele trata isso naturalmente, porém isso não está ocorrendo. (Li em: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/text-processing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa configurar o CloudSearch. Dá uma olhada em 'stemming options' e verifica as opções de idioma. Se tudo estiver correto, provavelmente você não está logado com o token de acesso.

Comment: Tudo está correto pelo que me parece. Stemming configurado, idioma em português, stemming amarrado aos campos, mas ainda assim quando eu busco sem acento ele não retorna os itens com acento. O que seria isso de estar logado com o token de acesso? A busca de teste que eu faço é no próprio console da AWSCS.